# How to force users to click on the link before they submit the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link on my page that has a rules about reservation. That link sits on the top of the page that user have to submit. I was wondering what would be the best way and how I can force them to click on that link(to read about the rules) before they submit their reservation? Is there any command in Javascript that can handle that?

Comment: set the submit button to "disabled" - have a a checkbox that must be clicked and have an onclick handler for that checkbox that changes the property of the submit button to not be disabled and to display a modal with the content you want them to read - or a link to another page etc. have a go and if you can't work out how to do it I can help with some code.

Comment: @gavgrif If you can provide just a small example that would be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disable the submit button first. And call a function onclick of the link that activates the button.

```js
function verify() {
  document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank" onclick="verify()">Terms</a>
<button id="submit" onclick="submit()" disabled>Submit</button>
```

Comment: I tried this code but problem is when I click on the link and go to other page I have to go back then to previous page to submit the form and my button is still disabled.

Comment: Set `target="_blank"`. That will open the linked document in a new window or tab

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="aRule" >Link of rule</a>
        <input type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit" />
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a#aRule').click(function () {
        $('input#btnSubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});
```